# sorting with terminal after grepping

Tags: sorting, unix, grep

I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on how I could sort a set of grepped values in unix.

for example if I have a list such as;

- qp_1_v2
- qp_50_v1
- qp_51_v4
- qp_52_v1
- qp_53_v1
- qp_54_v2
- qp_2_v1,

is there a way to sort numerically using the wildcard i.e sort qp_*_v1; where * would be read as a number and then sorted according to this (ignoring anything that came before and after the *). The problem I'm finding currently is that gp_52_v2 is always read as a string so I  have to cut gp_ and _v* to leave only the number and then sort.

I hope this makes sense...

Thanks in advance.

edit: A little addition that would be nice if anyone knows how to do it.. would be to grep and list values with the highest version i.e if gp_50 exists 3 times with the following suffixs _v1, _v2, _v3 it only lists gp_50_v3. As such this list will still consist of files with various versions but only the highest version of each file will be outputted to terminal.

Comment: Look at the [man page for sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort), particularly the `-n` switch (and possible the `-k` switch too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ls | cut -d '_' -f 2 | sort

in your case substitute ls for your grep command

Edit: In the example I put before the output is cut, if you want the original name of the file use this:

> ls | sort -k2,2g -t '_'
>
> **k** is the number of the field to compare
>
> **g** is the max number of characters to compare
>
> **t** is the delimiter

Comment: Thanks for clarifying all that. It helped a lot :)